# Forgot my root / sudo password

Tags: password

I forgot my sudo password, which is always asked for when I carry out any download in terminal. So I am unable to download any software.

Though I reset in recovery mode, again it's showing 'wrong password'. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Your sudo password is the same as the one you use at login.

Answer (score 2):

Restart your computer, in grub select `recovery mode` then select `root`. After that mount your partition with write permissions using `mount -o rw,remount /` then do `passwd {username of which user you want to change password }` and reset your passwords on the users you want.

Comment: would this also work if i use the inbuild encryption for the home directory? In other words, would i be able to bypass the encryption-password this way?

Comment: if you dont mind doing the testing, i would be glad to recieve the info on that.

Comment: @AlexOnLinux Asked some coworkers because, I don't use ubuntu and they said it's not possible to bypass the encryption. I can add that it probably can be cracked by brute force but it would take huge amount of processing power and time.

Comment: ah okay thx. i thought as root you would be able to chnge the users passwords, and in the end this would allow you to login as the user and get the directory decrypted.